# Is there a smooth function with an asymptote at zero and integrable over $]0,\infty[$?

Tags: improper-integrals

If you look at functions of the form $1/x^k$, $k>0$, it seems you can't have your cake and eat it too. If the integral of $1/x^k$ converges on $[1,\infty[$, then it diverges on $]0,1]$ and vice-versa, and if you try to balance things by picking $1/x$, your greediness is punished by having a function whose integral doesn't converge on both limits.

My question: can you construct a smooth function $f(x)$ that has a vertical asymptote at $x=0$ such that the integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx $$

converges?

What if I demand absolute convergence?

Comment: You can splice functions smoothly. Please see *bump function*. Chocolate cake, bump function, mango cake.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Technically it works, but it's kinda cheating. Can you do it without using a piecewise function?

Comment: I think there may be a law about discriminating against piecewise defined functions. And we can usually if we feel like it express a piecewise defined function using a single awkward formula.

Comment: Just ask for an analytic function, then.

Answer (score 2):

Use for example $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}e^{-x}$.

**Remark:** I prefer to note that we can smoothly splice two smooth functions together using a bump function defined over an arbitrarily short interval.

Comment: How would you use a bump function to construct an example for this problem?

Comment: @ougoah: There is a bump function $b(x)$ which is $1$ if $x\le 1$, $0$ for $x\ge 2$, and between $0$ and $1$ everywhere in the interval $(1,2)$. For $x\gt 0$, let $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}b(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

you can  take $f(x) =e^{-x} .$

Comment: That doesn't have a vertical asymptote at $x=0$ since $f(0)$ exists.